# Matlab: uitable with Logical cell and default value of 'true'

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I'm trying to build a uitable 1x2.

Cell(1,1) format is a 'logical'; Cell(1,2) is 'char'

```
handles.SeedTable = uitable(...
                    'ColumnName',{'Shuffle' 'Seed#'},...
                    'ColumnFormat',{'logical','char'},...
                    'ColumnEditable',[true true],...
                    'RowName',{'Seed'},...
                    'Data',[{'true'}, {'Random#'} ]);
```

When I run my file:
When I press the checkbox to uncheck cell(1,1) nothing happens.
If i do not set the cell to be true by default - all is good (i.e. remove the line:

```
'Data',[{'true'}, {'Random#'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the cell editable, the last `true` in your code needs to go without the quotes:

```
handles.SeedTable = uitable(...
                    'ColumnName',{'Shuffle' 'Seed#'},...
                    'ColumnFormat',{'logical','char'},...
                    'ColumnEditable',[true true],...
                    'RowName',{'Seed'},...
                    'Data',[{true}, {'Random#'} ]);
```